# Story about a school for people with superpowers that requires a ticket to enter that costs 1 million dollars

Tags: story-identification, urban-fantasy

I'm looking for a story about someone who goes to a school. You need a ticket to enter, but they cost 1 million dollars and the main character couldn't buy it. Then a guy named Fusion came along and bought it for them. The guy named fusion had blue hair and had a dark type of outfit. The They became friends shortly after that. The school is also for people that have superpowers. I can't remember the plot too well. But I suddenly dreamed about it and I felt really sad. I remembered a bunch of things but forgot once I woke up. I do not know the name or when I read this. But it was an amazing experience.

Comment: I've removed the last sentence from your question because that's not what this site is for; we don't do recommendations for works that are similar to something else.

Comment: And I've tried to summarise the story you're looking for in the title, so it might grab people's attention better. Also, welcome to the site! Take the [tour] to find out how things work here, and visit the [help] for more guidance. As you can see, we're quite an edit-happy community here at Stack Exchange. Hope you get a good answer soon.

Comment: Was this a novel, short story? Why did the Fusion character buy the ticket for the main character? If they had superpowers can you remember what any were? When did you read this? Why was the entry price so high? Can you remember what any of the characters looked like? Can you remember any of the plot/story? If you want to add anything to this you can [edit] the question.

Comment: Hmmm.  Sounds like a school for super powered criminals.  Swipe a million bucks with your super power, then pay it to the school so they can teach you how to use your super powers better.

Comment: Given how much collateral damage there is in comic books, I could picture a school for super powered kids costing a huge tuition.

Comment: This sounds vaguely like [PS238](https://ps238.nodwick.com/)?